# Adjusting subviews to keep their size using auto layout

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I have a UIView that contains subviews that looks like this:

[image]

This view was originally designed with 320 width in mind. iPhone 5s and lower. However I am now adapting it to work with iPhone 6+

The issue I am facing is getting the subviews width to grow to accommodate the extra space on the left and right of their super view. I can only seem to get the centre views width to grow, however not the out views. What constraints would I need to apply or change in order to get all views to grow a little to accommodate the extra space on the sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ScreenShot of views]

Hi!

If you design your view in interface builder, you may try this:

1- set all views to specific width and height
2- the view at the corner add pin to the edge with static value.
3- the view in the middle add pin to top or bottom, and add align constraint to horizontal centre of superview

Not sure if this help, Just try to answer!

Comment: This didn't do what I originally wanted. However the outcome was better. Now my views just have more space between them and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example of how to achieve this programmatically (with dummy views):

```
// Simple example demonstrating the below screenshots


// Create containers to hold each row of subviews
UIView *container1 = [UIView new];
container1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
container1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIView *container2 = [UIView new];
container2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
container2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

// Create the subviews
UIView *v1 = [UIView new];
v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
UIView *v2 = [UIView new];
v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIView *v3 = [UIView new];
v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v3.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
UIView *v4 = [UIView new];
v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v4.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
UIView *v5 = [UIView new];
v5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v5.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UIView *v6 = [UIView new];
v6.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
v6.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

// add the subviews
[container1 addSubview:v1];
[container1 addSubview:v2];
[container1 addSubview:v3];
[container2 addSubview:v4];
[container2 addSubview:v5];
[container2 addSubview:v6];

// Add the containers to the root view (in this case self.view)
[self.view addSubview:container1];
[self.view addSubview:container2];

// Add constraints for the containers
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[container1]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(container1)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[container2]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(container2)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-64.0-[container1(==100)]-[container2(==container1)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(container1, container2)]];

// Add constraints in both VFL and regular NSConstraints to the subviews of container 1
[container1 addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v1]-[v2(==v1)]-[v3(==v1)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1,v2,v3)]];
[container1 addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1)]];
[container1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

// Add constraints in both VFL and regular NSConstraints to the subviews of container 2
[container2 addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v4]-[v5(==v4)]-[v6(==v4)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v4,v5,v6)]];
[container2 addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v4]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v4)]];
[container2 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v5 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container2 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v5 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container2 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v6 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v4 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
[container2 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v6 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:container2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
```

Attached are screenshots on iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus respectively:

iPhone 5s
[image: iPhone 5s]

iPhone 6
[image: iPhone 6]

iPhone 6 Plus
[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

I hope this at least point you in the right direction =)

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction along with the marked answer to get the final result I was after. Thanks for the detail answer. I'll be using the VFL else where in my project like you demonstrated. :)

Answer (score 0):

disable autolayout and use autoresizing masks in the interface builder[Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)

Comment: My whole project uses auto layout extensively. Since this view is in my storyboard, I cannot turn AL off for one scene. Thanks though.